# PHP Email Sanitization Filter

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why my sanitize filter don't work. When entering an email with incorrect characters, it displays the email with incorrect characters. I would have thought it will strip out incorrect characters and only display the correct email address. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php       

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'data')){

$email = $_POST['data'];

//Now remove illegal characters
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
echo $email;

}
?>  

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="data">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the sample input and what output do you get?

Comment: Let's say I enter jp)(*&@gmail)**&.com I'm expecting the sanitize filter to strip out the incorrect characters and to give me jp@gmail.com

Comment: Parentheses are not allowed as part of a host or username but `*` is totally fine according to related RFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems to be working. I would however not want to store a different email than the exact input. If the incoming email adress is incorrect I would return an error message asking the user for a real email adress:

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'data')){
  $email = trim($_POST['data']);
  $sanitized = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if($email === $sanitized && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This is a valid email: " . $email;
  } else {
    echo "This is an invalid email: " . $email;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a test. I want to test out how the sanitization filter works. Currently its not doing what it's supposed to do - sanitizing the email.

Comment: Interesting - When I do a search for filter_sanitize_email on php.net I get a message that says filter_sanitize_email does not exist. Is this filter maybe deprecated?

Comment: It seems to me that FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL is not as strict as one intuitively might like. It does for instance remove ( and / but not #. However, I don't think it is meant to generate a "good-to-go" email adress. One needs to use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL afterwards to check if the adress truly is acceptable. :) (I don't think it has been deprecated. Look up this page http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php .)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what's you're looking for but just give it a try.

```
<?php
function filter_mail($string) {
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9.@\-]/', '', $string); // We remove special chars and accept only Alphs&Nums&.&@
}
$mail="jp)(*&@gmail)**&.com";
echo filter_mail($mail); //This will output the desired email
echo "<br>";
echo $mail; //This is how it was !
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help, after sanitizing we need to check if it is a valid mail

```php
<?php       
  if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'data')){
    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 

    $email = $_POST['data'];
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
      echo $email;
    } else {
      echo "invalid email";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: But that's the point - the filter_sanitize_email does not sanitize. I'm trying to test that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like only certain types of characters can get sanitized. For instance here are examples of wrong emails that will get sanitized:

(comment)localpart@example.com - After sanitization: commentlocalpart@example.com
"much.more unusual"@example.com - After sanitization: much.moreunusual@example.com

But these for instance will not get sanitized:

sarah{[@gmail}{[.com - After sanitization: sarah{[@gmail}{[.com
jp*&@gmail**&.com - After sanitization: jp*&@gmail**&.com